# LogMetric not working with microsoft extension framework

Tags: azure-log-analytics, microsoft-extensions-logging

I am using the logging extension framework in an asp.net core function app. I have following code:

```
log.LogMetric("TESTER", 0);
 
log.LogInformation($"{{logTypeStart}}: {service.GetType()}", logTypeStart);
await service.Run(log);
log.LogInformation($"{{logTypeEnd}}: {service.GetType()}", logTypeEnd);
```

In log analytics I query following:

```
AppTraces
AppMetrics
```

The LogInformation logs traces to the AppTraces in Log Analytics. But AppMetrics does not provide any results. Any pointers on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: is it a function v3? and are you using the ILogger to log messages? it's better  to providing more code(like a sample which we can use to repro/debug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it with Function V3, the metrics can be sent to both AI and the connected Log Analytics.

Please check the things below:

1.Test your code first locally(please follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62233510/application-insights-in-azure-function-app-core-v2) to see how azure function and application insights works locally), and see if the metrics can be shown in visual studio output. The screenshot is as below:

[image]

2.Please make sure the Azure log Analytics is actually connected with the AI you're using.

3.In Azure log Analytics, when query in `AppMetrics` table, make sure you have selected the proper `time range`. Here is the screenshot of my metrics:

[image]

Please let me know if any more issues.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated. LogMetric is working with asp.net core applications because Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage are installed. However in my sample I am working from a .NET standard library. I can log everything else fine, but I simply get a compiler error that LogMetric is not part of the framework, unless I am in an asp.net core project.

Comment: @ThomasSegato, ok. you should mention that in your question. I see the issue is in .net core azure function in the question:).

Comment: Yeah i will update. But the conclusion is that the Extension Framework does not include logmetric :( ?

Comment: @ThomasSegato, you can directly use the TrackMetric or GetMetric method of AI SDK.